# In Linux shell how to capture stderr to log file with datetime?

Tags: linux, shell

In my case, cmd1 handle multi-line(seems like awk or sed).

But the reliability of cmd1 is not good (90% success rate maybe, that is to say, 10 lines are not dealed within 100 lines input in a execution), so I wonder if there is way to caputer error message into log file(instead of '/dev/null' below) with additional timestamp?

```sh
cmd1 2>>/dev/null | cmd2 | cmd3 > stdout.log
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Acctually, cmd1 is a bulk query command which wraps a http api

Comment: `cmd1 2> >(...command to add timestamps... >log)`; see the linked duplicate re: what "...command to add timestamps..." should be.